# HTML5 Page Bottom Stick

Tags: javascript, html, footer

I have a page that I built with HTML. I put a clock on the bottom of the page in a single table cell. I have put things under that table/clock in the HTML file, but they appear above the table/clock. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```html
<head>
<center><p><h1 style="font-family:verdana">Start Page</h1></p>
<p></p>
Search
<form method="get" action="https://www.google.com/search">
<input type="text" name="q" size="31" value="">
</form>
</center>
</head>
<html>
<body bgcolor="#A0A0A0 ">
</body>
</html>
<body>
<html>

<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 15px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<table style="width:100%">
<table style="width:80%">
<col style="width:30%">
        <col style="width:30%">
        <col style="width:30%">
  <tr>
    <td><body link="#A60024" vlink="#A60024" alink="#0000FF"> <a href="https://drive.google.com">Google Drive</a></td>
    <td>t</td>  
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><body link="#A60024" vlink="#A60024" alink="#0000FF"> <a href="https://mail.google.com">Gmail</a></td>
    <td>Jackson</td>  
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>  
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</center>
<center><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p></p>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>



<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<table style="width:4%">
 


<p>
<h2><center>
<TD BGCOLOR="red"><b>Time</b></center></h2>
<script>
function startTime() {
    var today=new Date();
    var h=today.getHours();
    var m=today.getMinutes();
    var s=today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = h+":"+m+":"+s;
    var t = setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i<10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
</script>

<body onload="startTime()">

<div id="txt"></div>

</td>
</tr>
</p>
<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="http://starfireaerospace.com/index.php/login">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Login">
</FORM>
<p></p>
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Is this really your markup? Could you double check the correctness of your pasted code here? I mean, it starts off with a broken center tag, followed by two doctypes, and three body tags.

Comment: This is not my complete code. I included only the bottom of the code here so there would not be a wall of code. I will put the full version on?

Comment: Ok. I put the full code up.

Comment: Wow, do you did it on Dreamweaver? Your code are very dirty, there isn't a logic at all, you really need study more. Sorry, but most here won't help you if you at least can not write you code in right way, so little try to understand whatever you did here.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to clean up this document first. It's, ... I've never seen anything like it. Perhaps, in the process of cleaning it up, you will learn more about proper HTML structure, and it could even solve the specific issue you're asking about.

You can check HTML errors here: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

There's many more than 7, though. You will notice the last error says the validator can't continue (lol...)

Just start from the top and see what you can work out. If it's too much, try starting over. Here is a minimal structure for an HTML5 document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Notice there is only one doctype, only one head tag, and only one body tag. The order is important, too.

I'm not going to post a full HTML 101 response here, but I think this is a solid starting point to move forward from where you're at. Good luck!